# Flutter change Container Width from another Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, callback, widget, flutter-pageview

I have a `CustomAppBar` and a `PageViewer`. I would like to animate a *ProgressBar*  inside the `CustomAppBar`, if the user is changing the `Page`.

This is my Top-Level-Page looks like this:

```
class EntryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final List<Widget> _pages = [BasicValuesPage(), GeneralConditionPage()];
  int currentStep = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(
          scaleWidth(120),
        ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.secondary,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(
                  scaleWidth(20),
                ),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(
                  scaleWidth(20),
                ),
              )),
          child: AppBarContent(
            step: currentStep,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _buildPageViewer(),
      ),
    );
  }

  PageView _buildPageViewer() {
    return PageView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, position) {
        return _pages[position];
      },
      itemCount: _pages.length,
      onPageChanged: (int step) {
        currentStep = step;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I am using `AppBarContent` where I am passing `currentStep` which I updated at the bottom inside my `_buildPageView`, `onPageChanged`.

This is my `AppBarContent`:

```
class AppBarContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final int step;

  const AppBarContent({required this.step, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
         ProgressBar(
           step: step,
         ),
      ],
     );
    }
 }
```

And I as you can see I am also passing `step` to my `ProgressBar`, which is where I actually want to animate the `ContainerWidth`:

```
class ProgressBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final int step;

  const ProgressBar({required this.step, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double _containerWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - (2 * 16);
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: AppColors.white.withAlpha(37),
          height: scaleWidth(6),
          width: _containerWidth,
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
          width: _containerWidth * (step * 7),
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

My goal is that if the user changes the page, the `width` of the `AnimatedContainer` in my `ProgressBar` should be animated to the new `width`.

How can I achieve that? I searched for it but couldn't find anything. Any help is appreciated! Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this callback function

```dart
      onPageChanged: (int step) {
        currentStep = step;
      },
```

in `setState`:

```dart
      onPageChanged: (int step) {
        setState(){
          currentStep = step;
        }
      },
```

If you are using Dart version 2.1 integer literals may be directly used where double is expected, if older version you will have to additionally translate  your int step to double.